# Operadores lógicos com valor diferente

Tags: java, string, operadores

```
nome_adc_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       double percent =  (estimatedFare*0.20);
       double soma = estimatedFare + percent;
       double subtrai = estimatedFare - percent;
       if (nome_adc_1.isChecked()) {
           estimatedFare = soma;
       } else {
           estimatedFare = subtrai;
       }
       tvEstimatedFare.setText(getNewNumberFormat(estimatedFare));
   }
});
```

O código acima utilizo para um checkbox. Quando o checkbox está clicado, ele pega o valor da estimatedFare e adiciona 20%. funciona perfeitamente.
O problema é que quando desmarcado, a subtração que ele faz é diferente, o valor diminui cerca de 0.25 do valor total. Ou seja; se ficar marcando e desmarcando o checkbox, o valor mostrado chega a ir a zero. alguem sabe o motivo?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, isso ocorre por que vc está pegando 20% do resultado.

Exemplo:

Valor inicial do estimatedFare é 100.
Você marca ele adiciona 20 que é 20% de 100.
estimatedFare agora é 120.

Quando desmarcar, ele vai subtratir 20% de 120, que é 24.
O valor volta para 96.

Nesse cenário é melhor salvar o valor original e trabalhar com ele.

Comment: verdade, ta acontecendo exatamente isso! ao invés de ele subtrair a porcentagem do estimatedFare ele ta subtraindo a porcentagem do estimatedFare depois de +=.